# IE8 JavaScript Debugger: where the heck is the DOM tree?

Tags: dom, ie-developer-tools

I'm using the IE8 debugger to fix a script that works great in FF 3.16 and Chrome 12.0, but doesn't work for beans in IE 8.0 or Safari 5.0. The spot in the script that's giving me trouble is here:

[image]

I need to find the number of `<td>`s in the the `table id="main_tbody"` whose `children[0]` is the first row of data. Both FF and Chrome understand this perfectly; IE 8 and Safari 5 do not.

I want to look at the DOM tree in the IE 8 debugger to see what's going on. But I can't *find* the ding-dong DOM, dang it!

So: where ***is*** the DOM in the IE 8 debugger?

Alternatively <ahem!>: what's wrong with my JS code?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I should have said that the table is set up like this:

```
<table id ="main">
 <tbody id="main_tbody">
```

And references to `table id ="main"` and `tbody id="main_tbody"` are initialized this way:

```
  main                 = getRefToDiv( 'main' );             
  main_tbody           = getRefToDiv( 'main_tbody' );
```

Comment: Are there any error messages shown in the console and have you named your table "main_tbody" also? Because you dont seem to be using document.getElementById.

Comment: @K.A.G thanks, and please see the clarifying edit. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @K.A.G -- no, there are no console messages at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unbelievable. According to  [**quirksmode**](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_traversal.html), ie8 fails to implement **childElementCount** and I believe it because that's the thing that's coming back == 'undefined'. So I'll rewrite my loop with a new exit condition. That sucks, because now I'm going to get all children, including comments and everything else, not just the elements I was looking for. Incredible. FYI, ie8 also does not implement **firstElementChild**, **lastElementChild**, **nextElementSibling**, or **previousElementSibling**.

Answer (score 1):

Call the position_col_heads() function after your `</body>`
My suspicion is that this function is declared inside the head tag or being called before the browser renders the body content.

Just try this.

```
    ...
    ...
    </body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     position_col_heads();//Set breakpoint here and see if its accessible.
    </script>
</html>
```

Also, see what response you get for main.children[0] and main_tbody.innerHTML in your watch expression.